# How do I reach the middle tier using the memship class?

Tags: asp.net, membership, 3-tier

I have a 3-tier ASP.NET 2.0 app. I want to use the Membership.ValidateUser method of the membership class using the credentialls added with the login control. As stupid as it seems, I can't figure out how to have the ValidateUser control call anything but the db specified in the web.config. What I need is it to call down to the middle tier which will authenticate against the db. I can't have the presentation layer authenticate against the db directly.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a [custom membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e(VS.80).aspx), inherit from MembershipProvider then wire it up in the web.config. The provider could go in your App_Code folder then call your middle tier

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomProvider">
  <providers>
    <add 
      name="CustomProvider" 
      type="YourNameSpace.YourCustomProvider" 
      connectionStringName="ConnectionString" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```